# I need a solution for RnAlarmNotification.h file not found issue in ios app on xcode

Tags: react-native

My React native app working fine two days ago but when I  installed new library and did pod install then app is not running and showing error "RnAlarmNotification.h file not found" in ios app on xcode.

I tried to run application for implementing Stripe 3ds but app is not running. now I need to solve "RnAlarmNotification.h" file not found issue to further development.

[Screen shot the error what issue I am facing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzJ0A.jpg)

Comment: try by doing manual installation given there,
https://github.com/emekalites/react-native-alarm-notification

or first, delete a node-modules folder, and a pods folder, lock files then run yarn install or npm install then cd ios and pod install.

Comment: @JatinBhuva ok , let me check and thanks for the support.